# The Hash Symbol in Numerical character references

Tags: html, w3c

My question is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9737766/numerical-character-reference-entities-nomenclature), but didn't find my answer there.

From the [link](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/latin1.html), I could gather that HTML supports the display of ISO 8859/1 8-bit single-byte coded graphic characters, through numerical representations such as:

`&32;` for Space.

`&33;` for Exclamation mark.

The above won't be resolved unless the entity names are prefixed with the `#`:

`&#32;` for Space would be resolved.

`&#33;` for Exclamation mark would be resolved.

What is the reason for prefixing the entity names with the `#` symbol for these characters, when the ISO Latin 1 Character Entities do not follow the same standards. 
It can be deduced that the HTML parser would be written in such a way to deal with these, but it would be great to know why this standard was introduced in the first place.

Comment: What do you mean by "ISO Latin 1 Character Entities do not follow the same standards"? Also just btw, you can use numeric character references for the entire Unicode range.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen - Thanks for the response. `ISO Latin 1 Character Entities`, do not require the entity names to be prefixed by the `#` symbol.

Comment: Oh! I didn't notice because you added the `#`s back in your post. Maybe you should remove them so people can actually see what you're talking about.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen - That would make it more clear. Have edited my post.

Comment: Also you did notice that you linked to a pretty ancient spec (HTML 3), right? I can't find a mention of numeric character references without a `#` in [HTML 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/charset.html#h-5.3.1) for instance.

Comment: Thanks for the link. It has it there in the document, but i would also like to why numerical characters cannot be handled the same way without the `#` symbol, would there have been any specific reason for this.

Comment: HTML 3 caused lots of problems and was never implemented, superseded by HTML 3.2. Most probably, implementing numeric character references without hashes caused backward compatibility problems - pages that were written expecting `&33;` to display as `&33;` suddenly displayed as `!` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The full gory details of how these are processed is detailed in the [parsing section of the HTML 5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/syntax.html#character-reference-in-data-state). You notably want to read the links to "[consume a character reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/syntax.html#consume-a-character-reference)".

HTML 3 was never relevant, and even HTML 3.2 was superseded *long* ago. ISO documents are also irrelevant in this context.

Following the parsing algorithm can be painful (at least, it takes some getting used-to), but it is guaranteed correct.

Comment: Thanks for the links, but the answer and contents in the links still don't answer my question.